# Как вызвать какую-то функцию при остановке телеграм бота? aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Я храню данные в JSON. При включении бота я подгружаю данные с файла в словарь, но при выключении мне нужно их выгружать обратно в файл, только не знаю как вызвать функцию при остановке бота.

Пробовал

```
executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=load_data(), on_shutdown=upload_data())
```

но выполняет функцию почему-то при запуске после стартапа. Помогите плз

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать функции `load_data` и `upload_data`, затем в `on_startup`  и `on_shutdown` передавать ссылки на эти функции

```
executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=load_data, on_shutdown=upload_data)
```

попробуй это:

```
# загрузка данных при старте бота
def load_data():
    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

# сохранение данных при остановке бота
def upload_data():
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data()
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=load_data, on_shutdown=upload_data)
```

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка, TypeError: load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Вот код функции выгрузки данных: 
def upload_data():
with open("data/all_records.json", "w") as file:
json.dump(all_records, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: изменил, попробуй внести правки

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, но смог решить. В upload_data и load_data добавил аргументы self и сделал их асинхронными.

Comment: ```async def start(self):
        self.data = await self.load_data()
        # запуск бота

    async def stop(self):
        await self.upload_data()
        # остановка бота``` так?

Comment: executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=load_data, on_shutdown=upload_data) | async def load_data(self): *code* | async def upload_data(self): *code*